# Storing points for a 3D maze with irregular spacing?

Tags: python, data-structures, maze

A while back I made an abstract 3D maze thing in Python with the depth first search method, where I stored each fork in a dictionary as a list of points, and used a separate dictionary to store which fork each fork originated from. This worked (as can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GVi1cFTdY8) following one of the last points to the origin), but it seemed a bit of a messy way, and got a bit too hacky trying to get the pathfinding working with it.

If you look [on this site](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/) at the maze generation part, it looks like it's just a grid of points, and inbetween each point there can either be a connection or wall. I may be wrong and it might just be different sized cubes that treat every 2nd one as a wall/connector, but I would be interested to know if there's a better way of doing this in Python. Storing it in a pre built 3D grid is out of the question, as I don't want it limited by bounds (you can easily generate many thousands of points), and plus the size changes as the generation goes on, as it looks cooler for massive generations when it goes smaller.

I understand this question may not be fit for SO, but I only found tips on generating mazes and not storing them when searching, so thought it'd possibly be worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question right or if this will help for the visualization of the maze but if you'd like to just store the structure or paths while you are traversing you can use a modified [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) with some extra information like color to tell if you visited a node. The linked list could have a list of children like a fork would. Each node could have a location like the blocks in the video you linked.

A python example of a node object for a list like this could be

```
class node:

  def __init__(self, color, location, parent, children):
    self.nodeColor = color
    self.location = location
    self.parentNode = parent
    self.children = children
```

Where the parent is a node object and the children are a list of node objects.

The color attribute can be used when doing a depth first search or any kind of search. If you visit a node color it black, if the node is on the exploration horizon color it grey, if a node has not been visited or seen initialize it to be white.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That seems like a nice idea, would you store each node in a list, and use its index when linking it with other nodes? As I've not really used classes in this way, would it scale well memory wise for a large generations such as 100,000 points? The one advantage of my old way is it handled large numbers quite well. The colour idea is interesting, but as I went down the 'pick a point at random and try fork out' approach, checking that point for something first seems an unnecessary step :)   Here's another example by the way - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkHEVtgiLUA

Comment: Because a maze can be structured as a tree if you would not have to store each node instance in a list or any of the python data structures. Each class would have a *pointer* to the next node in the line. You could easily generate millions of these nodes without any big memory repercussions. To link the nodes with other nodes you could have a function that allows a node to gain a child which appends the child node to the internal children list.

Comment: Ah ok cool, I hadn't realised it'd only store pointers, though am I right in thinking that is mainly only good for if you aren't saving anything? Also, unless I'm missing something, for every new point generated, wouldn't you have to walk through the entire tree just to find the location of each point to make sure there are no collisions? I've thought about it a bit while writing this and it seems the list approach may work best for me, I'd be interested to know about the collision checking though with the pointer way :P

Comment: Managed to get it all done this morning including the pathfinding, I'm really surprised as to how easy the twin links made things haha. I tested it against my old code, which does admittedly have a few more things going on, but it's around 1.5x faster this way :)